# Best way to convert values to/from 0-99 and 0-100 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

What's the best way to convert values to/from a range of 0-99 and 0-100?

For example, Homebridge MQTT-Thing (using Node.js and JavaScript) only supports values of 0-100.  However, my zwavejs2mqtt devices only support 0-99.

What's the best way to convert values to/from both of these systems using JavaScript?  (ie. MQTT-Thing supports custom JavaScript functions to encode/decode messages where I can convert the values)

Comment: In the variables you could declare it as an object where one value determines whether it is a max of 99 or 100.

Comment: Use a scale operation to convert from 99 to 100 forward, and from 100 to 99 backwards.  Like so forwards,    `valueMQTT_From_JS = (valueJS / 99) * 100`  where the 99 is the MQTT denominator, and the 100 is the max value of the JS.   `valueJS_FROM_MQTT = (valueMQTT / 100) * 99`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks!  What's the best way to convert the result to an integer?  Math.floor() ?

Comment: Yes. I forgot the result is not an integer,  Math.floor(), or more usefully Math.round()